# Javascript Path object path into a function and update object

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Javascript and want to pass a object path to the function and update the object. Why would the object not be updated? and is there a slick way of getting it to work besides returning, or besides passing the entire object to the function and specify the path inside? thx

```
var stock={
    basket:{
        apple:3,
        orange:2
    },
    table:{
        apple:5,
        orange:5
    }
};
function change(path, amount){
    path+=amount;
}

// calling function
change (stock.table.apple,-2);
console.log(stock.table.apple);
```

Comment: The stock.table.apple should update to 3 after calling the "change" function, but it's not updated, and shows 5 still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `stock.table.apple` is not a reference. It is the value `5`. Hence:

```
  change(stock.table.apple, -2)
= change(5,                 -2)

    path   = 5
    amount = -2

    path += amount

        path   = 3
        amount = -2
```

As you can see, the `path += amount` changes the value of `path` and not the value of `stock.table.apple`.

One way to work around this is as follows:

```js
var stock = {
    basket: {
        apple:  3,
        orange: 2
    },
    table: {
        apple:  5,
        orange: 5
    }
};

function change(object, key, amount) {
    object[key] += amount;
}

change(stock.table, "apple", -2);

alert(stock.table.apple);
```

The above code works because `stock.table` is a reference value. The following answer will help you understand the difference between reference values and primitive values:

[Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268731/783743)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change(path, amount){
    var key = Object.keys(path)[0];
    path[key] += amount;
}

// calling function
change (stock.table,-2);
console.log(stock.table.apple);
```

you can send only part for update

Comment: A hack like `Object.keys(path)[0]` is not a very good solution. You shouldn't rely on the object key order: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9179680/783743

Answer (score 0):

This one was tricky. You are calling `change` function with the value stored in the `stock.table.apple`, not the actual path.

Your function call is `change(5, -2)`.

You can pass an object reference + path as a string:

```
change(stock, "table.apple", -2) // look for attributes of the stock object
```

or the whole path as a string, like:

```
change("stock.table.apple", -2) // look for attributes of the window object
```